# What is this framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

So basically, just stumbled upon a framework or other feature of PHP, which I haven't seen. All functions are written in PHP - oop type, but html files are somewhere really deep (in folders), and here is example of one of html file -

http://jsfiddle.net/x2tgt/

code -

```
<h1>{$category[0].name}</h1>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    {section name=id loop=$products}
    <tr>
        {section name=id2 loop=$products[id]}
        {if $products[id][id2].id}
        <td width="100%" valign="top" width="130">
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="left" width="195">
                        <a href="{$smarty.const._URL_ROOT}/{$page.lang}/product/{$products[id][id2].id}/{if $page.eshop eq 1}1/{/if}"><img src="{$smarty.const._URL_PREFIX}/data/img/{$products[id][id2].filename}_list.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15"></td>
                    <td valign="top" align="left">
                        <a href="{$smarty.const._URL_ROOT}/{$page.lang}/product/{$products[id][id2].id}/{if $page.eshop eq 1}1/{/if}"><h1>{$products[id][id2].name}</h1></a>
                        {if $page.eshop eq 1}
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="prodListPrice">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" class="top">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="middle">
                                    ##PROD_PRICE_1##<br/>
                                    <span>{$products[id][id2].price_1} {$products[id][id2].price_from|stripslashes}</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle">
                                    ##PROD_PRICE_2##<br/>
                                    <span>{$products[id][id2].price_2} {$products[id][id2].price_from|stripslashes}</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" class="bottom">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        {/if}
                        <div class="br5"></div>
                        <div>{$products[id][id2].stext|stripslashes}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        {else}
        <td>
        </td>
        {/if}
        {/section}
    </tr>​
```

Do you have any clues what type of framework this could be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) template. I 'm not sure which (if any) frameworks use Smarty as their view templating engine.

Comment: Thanks ;)! Gonna have a look on it.

Comment: I guess it could be anything from Zend to Symfony which could run with Smarty. Even Oxid (yeah, it's not a framework) uses Smarty.

Comment: Well basically, I was surprised about the HTML template style :D. Gonna have a look on it. Is Smarty out-dated, or is it popular today also? P.S. Jon, will accept your answer ASAP.

Comment: I use Smarty in this and my last job so its not out-dated. It's not bad and if something doesn't do what you want, you can create your own smarty code too.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is a template engine and not a framework. One can use smarty in any of the existing frameworks. Some eCommerce and CMS systems still use smarty like X-cart. If you find something in smarty that can be useful to you like caching of the tamplates, you can configure smarty with any of the framework you like.